# How to get max date from one column and match with other column in Excel?

Tags: excel, max

I have excel sheet data like below

```
CustomerNo LoginDate
101        25/05/2012
101        10/05/2012
101        20/05/2012
101        10/04/2012
102        21/05/2012
102        12/04/2012
103        20/05/2012
104        08/04/2012
```

I want to get last login date match with customer number and result like below.

```
101   25/05/2012
102   21/05/2012
103   20/05/2012
104   08/04/2012
```

Comment: Did you tried anything?
Post your code so we can help you and explain your problem better than this Ravi.

Comment: Thanks Aamer but need this one using excel formula only. so i cant use any .net code

Comment: My bad, I am too bad in excel formulas! sorry Ravi, I can't help you with this!
^_^

Comment: In which language, you are trying to achieve this.

Comment: Romil i am not trying any code language..just with in excel sheet i need to find last login date for each customer

Answer (score 0):

You may use the DMAX function to do this.

First, I am putting CustomerNo in A1 and 08/04/2012 in B9. Then I am naming that range "theTable".

Second, I add A11 and B11 my Criteria, "CustomerNo" and "LoginDate".

Then in A12, I place 101.

Finally I am ready for my DMAX function.

In B12, I place `=DMAX(theTable,"LoginDate", A11:A12)`

Excel will place 25/05/2012 in B12.

Comment: Thanks all,  I found it in simple way.  1) First i used Advanced filter `Data --> Advanced` in **Data** menu to get distinct record on customer no and placed it in new column.  2) Based on the new column value apply formula `=MAX(($A$2:$A$9=$C2)*$B$2:$B$9)` and **press Ctrl + Shift + Enter**

Comment: @Ravi : You genius, you should send that as answer! Thank you just solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You could try a pivot table. This has the nice ability to get the max for all customer numbers at once and can be updated quickly if any of the data changes.

- Select your nicely-formatted table
- Insert | Pivot Table
- Drag `CustomerNo` to `Row Labels`
- Drag `LoginDate` to `Values`
- Change the `Value Field Settings` (e.g., by right clicking any value in the pivot table) to `Summarize by` `Max`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. With array function (Press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`):

`=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$9=C2,$B$2:$B$9))`

2. Regular formula:

`=MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$9=C2)*($B$2:$B$9),,1))`

I personally like the 2nd way better since array function will slow down PC performance for huge data.  Anyway, hope this helps.