# Excel large function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to find the X most recent results for a given tennis player in a table with fields for player name (column A), date (column B) and result ("W" or "L" in column C).

I've tried using the large function with the date field in different ways but nothing seems to work. E.g.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$30,"andy murray",$B$2:$B$30,LARGE($B$2:$B$30,{1,2,3,4,5}),$C$2:$C$30,"W")

=AND($A$2:$A$30="andy murray",$B$2:$B$30=LARGE($B$2:$B$30,1),$C$2:$C$30="W")
```

Repeating this last one when k=2, k=3 etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: picture from comments]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755207/how-to-get-max-date-from-one-column-and-match-with-other-column-in-excel

Comment: What information are you trying to return?  The date?, player name?, the result?  This should be doable with an array formula, but how it's built is very specific to how things are set up and what output is desired.  A picture of the data with expected input/output would be very helpful.  If not that, then a sample of the input/ouput data as text would be good.  If you add a link to a picture, I will edit it in to the post.

Comment: Thanks for this.  The information I'm trying to get is the number of wins in the last (e.g.) 10 games. The site won't let me post pictures unfortunately, this link might work [link] https://www.flickr.com/photos/134075200@N04/shares/SM921b If not, the table is set out like this: column A Name - Andy Murray, Gael Monfils... column B Date - 25/05/15, 16/04/15... column C Result - W, L... So the desired result would be e.g. 'of Andy Murray's 10 most recent games, 6 were wins and 4 were losses'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with something like this:

```
=MAX(IF((A2:A18="Andy Murray")*(C2:C18="W"), B2:B18))
```

OR

```
=MAX(IF(A2:A18="Andy Murray", B2:B18))
```

NOTE: After putting in the formula you have to hit SHIFT + CTRL + ENTER on a PC or COMMAND + ENTER on a Mac. Very important.

The top one gives you the most recent win, the bottom one gives you most recent game played.